# Hodge star related question

Tags: differential-geometry

If we have expression (1) $$\star (F \wedge d\alpha)$$ where $$ (F \wedge d\alpha)$$ is a $2$-form field strength ($F$ and $d\alpha$ are 1 forms)and $\star$ represents [Hodge star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual).

How can we simplify this rather more?

I want to exterior derive expression (1) and was wondering if I can simplify it before applying exterior derivative on it?

To elaborate my question: The Hodge dual on, let's say, $d(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$is any complex function can easily be deducted as one applies the Hodge Duality rule. Why? Because $d(\alpha)$ can be written as $\partial _x \alpha dx + \partial _y \alpha dy + \partial _z dz$ and we know how to go from this expression to its dual because we know that $\star dx$ let's say is $dy \wedge dz$ in 3 spatial coordinates, but here we don't know how to apply the rule..

Comment: This is currently a pure math question.

Comment: I edited that by saying that the 2 form is a field strength. I actually encountered that in a physics problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that you can simplify in this, except if some further simplification comes from the explicit form of $F$ and $\alpha$. Also the action of the Hodge operator on basis element is well defined (cf. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Computation_of_the_Hodge_star)).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\omega = \star(F\wedge d\alpha)$. Then
$\star\omega = \star ^2 F\wedge d\alpha \Rightarrow$
$\star\omega = (-1)^{n(n-p)}F\wedge d\alpha$, where $n$ is the dimension of manifold and $p$ is the degree of $\star(F\wedge d\alpha)$.
Then applying the exterior derivative at both sides we obtain
$d\star\omega = (-1)^{n(n-p)}dF\wedge d\alpha$
Applying $\star$ again we gain
$\delta \omega = (-1)^{n(n-p)}\star(dF\wedge d\alpha) \Rightarrow$
$\delta \star (F\wedge d\alpha) = (-1)^{n(n-p)}\star(dF\wedge d\alpha)$